# Listview Columns Error

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a bit of a problem. I have got a ListView named lstPers with 4 Columns. What I would like to do is disable editing of the text in the columns. So I found this command on StackOverflow

```
lstPers.Columns["Nume persoana"].ReadOnly = true;
```

but it gives this error:

> *"System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader' does not contain a definition
>   for 'ReadOnly' and no extension method 'ReadOnly' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader' could be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"*

I have been searching for the references but no luck in that. Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: Where do you run this code? Inside a Form class or in a different class?

Comment: In a win form. Here's the code that creates the ListView's columns. (not the full code)

            // Attach Subitems to the ListView
            lstPers.Columns.Add("Nume persoana", 200, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
            lstPers.Columns.Add("CNP", 120, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
            lstPers.Columns.Add("Data nasterii", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
            lstPers.Columns.Add("Profesia", 150, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
            lstPers.Columns.Add("Adresa", 250, HorizontalAlignment.Left);"

Comment: The list view is created, works good. Just needs a little tweek to make it read only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable editing the `Items` use this:

```
lstPers.LabelEdit = false;
```

Note that in a `Winforms Listview` all other `Columns` (`SubItems`) can't be edited anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The ListView.Columns property gives you only the column headers.

Perhaps you want the DataGridView control? Its Columns property gives you the whole column, and those columns have a ReadOnly property. You can also set their ReadOnly property through the designer, too.